# Resizing of UIView in Visual Studio with Xamarin IOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin

I try to make a list of items in native iOS UI in Visual Studio with Xamarin. For list I use UITableView, for item UITableViewCell. Item include image and label. Image have to fill TableViewCell. Label is placed in bottom part of TableViewCell. Label fill TableViewCell by width and have a constant height.

Here the image from VS designer how it should be

[image: image of cell in designer]

But when I opened this list on Simulator/Device TableViewCell is about 3/4 of screen height.

[image: image of cell in device]

Hope anybody can help me with this.

Comment: Did [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/tables/autosizing-row-height/) help?  Have you solved it ?

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. But it works only if all images are with the same aspect ratio.

1. In window of iOS ui designer in VS you need to select Constraints
   mode
2. Select the image and click on "I" sign to the right of image (on the
   first image in the post this "I" sign is to the right of stars.
3. After click context menu will appear. You need to select second
   option ("Aspect Ratio") and set what you need (1:1 for my example).

Image will always stay in this AR and change size of TableViewCell if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the item height using the `RowHeight` property on `UITableView` by setting it to an `int`.

```
tableView.RowHeight = 150;
```

You can also implement autosized items according to the tutorial in the [Xamarin.iOS documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/tables/autosizing-row-height/).

Comment: Nope. Row height have to be dynamic

Comment: Why didn't the link help? Have you hit a problem there?

Comment: Because I created this TableViewCell according this link. And result is on 2-nd image in my post.